# Android - Refresh Contents of ViewPager after data has changed

Tags: android-viewpager, refresh

I am very new to android development and my question may sound silly, but its really giving me tough time getting it solved. There are plenty of questions and solutions on this very particular topic but none of them seems to be working for me. So my problem is simple i load weeks of day in an Action Bar Tabs with ViewPager, when i swipe or select a page / tab the data in my view is not refreshing. I have tried notifyDataSetChanged(), i could not get the getItemPosition work.

Here is my code of viewPager

```
        public class EventAgenda extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


            SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

            ViewPager mViewPager;
            private ActionBar actionBar;
            Integer eventID, dateCount;
            String sessionDate, selectedDate;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_agenda);

                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    eventID = extras.getInt("EVENT_ID");
                    EventDetailController eventDetails = new EventDetailController(this);
                    final List<EventDetails> events = eventDetails.getEventDays(eventID);
                    dateCount = events.size();

                    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
                    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

                    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
                    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // set background for action bar tab
                    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFDE00")));
                    // Adding Tabs
                    for (int i = 0; i < dateCount; i++) {
                        String theDate = String.valueOf(events.get(i).getEventDate());

                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
                        Date myDate = null;
                        try {
                            myDate = dateFormat.parse(theDate);

                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MM-yyyy");
                        sessionDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

                        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(sessionDate)
                                .setTabListener(EventAgenda.this));

                    }
                    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            // on changing the page
                            // make respected tab selected
                            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                        }

                        public int getItemPosition(Object object) { //This never gets called and does not allow me override as well
                            Log.v("getItem Posistion ", object.toString());
                            return 0;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_event_agenda, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                 int id = item.getItemId();

                if(id==R.id.action_refresh) { //this code on Refresh does refresh the data in the View but i want it to work on swipe and tab selection
                    int pos=mViewPager.getCurrentItem();//to get the sposition of the current page
                    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
                    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);//to get it to the right position
                }
                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // on tab selected
                // show respected fragment view

                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                selectedDate = String.valueOf(tab.getText());
                CommonConstants.SESSION_DATE = selectedDate;

                mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Log.v("EM Title : ", String.valueOf(tab.getText()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }



            public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

                public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);
                }

                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
                    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

                        CommonConstants.SESSION_DATE = selectedDate;
                        Fragment fragment = null;
                        fragment = new EventDayFragment(); //This is the only Fragment i have i am passing the selectedDate as Bundle
                        //refreshContents();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("sessionDate", selectedDate);
                        args.putInt("eventID", eventID);
                        fragment.setArguments(args);

                    return fragment;

                }
                @Override
                public int getCount() {

                    return dateCount;
                }

                @Override
                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                        case 1:
                            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                        case 2:
                            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }

           //Here i tried putting the refresh code into following function and tried calling it from getItem but it crashes
            private void refreshContents(){
                int pos=mViewPager.getCurrentItem();//to get the sposition of the current page
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
                mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);//to get it to the right position
            }



        }
```

Here is Code of my only Fragment

```
        public class EventDayFragment extends Fragment{
            ListView lvSession;
            String dateString;
            Integer eventID;

        public static EventDayFragment newInstance() {
            EventDayFragment fragment = new EventDayFragment();
            return fragment;
        }


        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_event_agenda_main, container, false);

                lvSession = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_sessions);

                dateString= getArguments().getString("sessionDate");
                eventID = getArguments().getInt("eventID");
                Log.v("EM Date String", dateString);

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date convertedDate = new Date();
                try {
                    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //ListView lvEvents = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_events);
                EventDetailController eventDetails = new EventDetailController(getContext());
                List<EventDetails> sessionList = eventDetails.getEventDetailsDate(convertedDate, eventID);
                CommonConstants.ACTIVITY_NAME ="SESSIONS";

                final MultiColumnListViewAdapter multiColRowAdapter = new MultiColumnListViewAdapter(getContext()) {
                    @Override
                    public View.OnClickListener getListener(final Integer id) {

                        return new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SessionDetails.class);
                                intent.putExtra("EVENT_ID", id);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        };
                    }
                };


                multiColRowAdapter.getObjects().addAll(sessionList);
                lvSession.setAdapter(multiColRowAdapter);

                return rootView;

        }


        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Please help me to sort it out....
thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys have not heard from any of you.... need your help to sort it out...

Answer (score 0):

Guys i solved the issue by storing the session dates in an array and later on passing the respective index value as per the tabs position in getItem.